# ObservableList will not display on TableView because of "Duplicate TableColumns" (JAVAFX)

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, fxml

I'm trying to display data from my ObservableList into a TableView, which I created in SceneBuilder. The TableView contains three TableColumns. I've given them the exact same name as in the FXML-file.

I've imported them into the Controller like you can see down below [1]

And then I'm trying to run my code. I basically have a song. The song consists of a title, artist and album. I want to display it on each column, but it keeps complaining about:

Duplicate TableColumns detected in TableView columns list with titles 'Song title', 'Artist', 'Album'.

And then crashes.

Anybody know what Im doing wrong?

```
@FXML
private TableView<Song> defaultTableView;

// 1) Song Title

@FXML
private TableColumn songTitleColumn;

// 2) Song artist

@FXML
private TableColumn songArtistColumn;

// 3) Song album
@FXML
private TableColumn songAlbumColumn;


public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {


    Song song1 = new Song("a lot.mp3");

    Song song2 = new Song("Work Out.mp3");

    Song song3 = new Song("Jesus Walks.mp3");

    Playlist myPlaylist = new Playlist("My awesome playlist");

    myPlaylist.addSong(song1);

    myPlaylist.addSong(song2);

    song1.getSongTitleFromDB();

    song1.getSongArtistFromDB();

    song1.getSongAlbumFromDB();

    myPlaylist.displayAllSongs(defaultTableView,songTitleColumn,songArtistColumn,songAlbumColumn);

    ObservableList<Song> songs = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    songs.add(song1);

    songTitleColumn.setCellFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Song,String>("songTitle"));

    songArtistColumn.setCellFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Song, String>("songArtist"));

    songAlbumColumn.setCellFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Song, String>("songAlbum"));


    defaultTableView.setItems(songs);

    defaultTableView.getColumns().addAll(songTitleColumn,songArtistColumn,songAlbumColumn);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your fxml file looks something like this:

```xml
<TableView fx:id="defaultTableView">
    <columns>
        <TableColumn fx:id="songTitleColumn"/>
        <TableColumn fx:id="songArtistColumn"/>
        <TableColumn fx:id="songAlbumColumn"/>
    </columns>
</TableView>
```

Since `columns` is a readonly list property, loading the fxml file results in the columns being added to the `TableView`. Trying to add them another time to the `TableView` results in the exception.

You do this in the `initialize` method:

```
defaultTableView.getColumns().addAll(songTitleColumn, songArtistColumn, songAlbumColumn);
```

You need to remove this link or do **all of** the column creation in the `initialize` method.